# Linq to sql issue in C# forms application with .mdf database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having issues with a C# form application. I am connecting to a .mdf database and trying to query for a column named SpotLanding that is a bool and then count the number that are true. It is in LogbookDatabase.mdf and is in table EnterTable. Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void SpotLandingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataContext db = new DataContext(@"C:\LogbookDatabase.mdf");
        Table<EnterTable> entrytable = db.GetTable<EnterTable>();
        var spot = (from SpotLanding in entrytable
                    where SpotLanding = true
                    select SpotLanding).Count;

        return spot;
    }
```

This is the error it is giving me;

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'ParagliderLogBook.EnterTable'

Any info anyone could provide would be great. I have tried so many different ways to complete this and come up with the same error.

Comment: dunno if this is the only problem, but you are assigning, not comparing "= true" should be "== true"

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `SpotLanding` member of your object (which by the way, should *not* also be called `SpotLanding` as that is just confusing).

Also you can write your query much more concisely using [the overload of `Count` that takes a predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
int spot = entrytable.Count(x => x.SpotLanding);
```

Comment: Even better, `entryTable.Count(x => x.SpotLanding)`.

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks, yes you are right... that's much better! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
where SpotLanding = true
```

you're trying to assign a boolean value instead comparing it.

```
where SpotLanding == true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the == operator instead of =

```
var spot = (from SpotLanding in entrytable
                where SpotLanding == true
                select SpotLanding).Count;
```